# Getting timeout on UDP socket when timeout is set to 'None' - Python

Tags: python, udp

I am writing a connector using UDP in Python 3.3

When I am sending data to the UDP port, everything works fine.  The problem is that when I am not sending any data, I get an error generated by the receiving port once per minute that says "timed out".  While debugging, I used the socket.gettimeout() function and it returned 'None'.

Why am I getting this timeout error? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import socket
from EventArgs import EventArgs
import logging
class UDPServer(object):
"""description of class"""

def __init__(self, onMessageReceivedEvent = '\x00'):
    self.__onMessageReceivedEvent = onMessageReceivedEvent
    self.__s = '\x00'
    self.__r = '\x00'

def openReceivePort(self,port):
    try:
        self.__r = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.__r.bind(("",port))
        print ("opening port: ", port)

    except socket.error as e:
        logging.getLogger("ConnectorLogger").critical(e)


def openBroadcastPort(self):
    try:
        self.__s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.__s.bind(("",2101))
        print ("opening port: ", 2101)

    except socket.error as e:
        logging.getLogger("ConnectorLogger").critical(e)

def closePorts():
    if self.__r != '\x00':
        self.__r.close()
    if self.__s != '\x00':
        self.__s.close()

def getUDPData(self):
    try:
        data, addr = self.__r.recvfrom(1024)
        if self.__onMessageReceivedEvent != '\x00':
            eventArgs = EventArgs()
            eventArgs.Addr = addr
            eventArgs.Data = data
            self.__onMessageReceivedEvent.fire(self, eventArgs)
    except socket.error as e:
        logging.getLogger("ConnectorLogger").critical(e)

def send(self,ipAddress,port,message):
    try:
        self.__s.sendto(message.encode(),(ipAddress,23456))
    except socket.error as e:
            logging.getLogger("ConnectorLogger").critical(e)
```

Comment: Why do you think that timeout = None means that there is no timeout?

Comment: Probably because the documentation for `socket.gettimeout()` says "Return the timeout in seconds (float) associated with socket operations, or None if no timeout is set."

Comment: My assumption is that 'None' or 'no timeout' means that it would never timeout.  The problem is that it is timing out, once per minute.  Am I wrong in assuming a timeout that is 'None' would never time out? The documentation says that the exception socket.timeout is "raised when a timeout occurs on a socket which has had timeouts enabled via a prior call to settimeout()", but I haven't made any calls to settimeout()

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my own problem.  I was using the default configuration for socket.setblocking which is 0 (non-blocking). The documentation says that using this configuration is the equivalent of using a settimeout value of 0. If I use a blocking socket, it is the equivalent of using a settimeout value of 'None'.  Once I changed to a blocking socket I no longer saw this error.

**socket.setblocking(flag**)-Set blocking or non-blocking mode of the socket: if flag is 0, the socket is set to non- blocking, else to blocking mode. Initially all sockets are in blocking  mode. In non-blocking mode, if a recv() call doesn’t find any data, or if a send() call can’t immediately dispose of the data, a error exception is raised; in blocking mode, the calls block until they can proceed. s.setblocking(0) is equivalent to s.settimeout(0.0); s.setblocking(1) is equivalent to s.settimeout(None)*